# How do I build an array in JS where some elements are conditional?

Tags: javascript, arrays, conditional-statements

I want to build an array that may or may not contain some elements, depending on user roles. Can I achieve this at "build time", or do I have to first create the array without the conditional elements, and then manually add them with the splice option? Order matters!

This is what I want to achieve...:

```
var myList = [
    { obj1 },
    { obj2 },
    if userRoleX==true {
        { obj3 },
    }
    { obj4 },
];
```

Any thoughts?

Comment: you could make obj3 be something like user.obj3

Comment: Can you build the array with known values, and default values for the conditional elements? Then populate the conditional elements when you determine what they should be.

Comment: if order maters  might be easier to remove them using [filter()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) It creates a new array based on conditions in callback

Comment: Maybe you're trying to achieve something like this - [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/cz6nP/). *FYI*: Your question is unclear, so if you add more details it will be easier for us to help to solve your problem.

Answer (score -3):

You can build an array with elements as needed:

```
var i = 0;
var myList = [];
myList[i++] = obj1;
myList[i++] = obj2;
if (userRoleX) {
    myList[i++] = obj3;
}
myList[i++] = obj4;
```

You can even skip indexes or provide non-numeric indexes like so:

```
myList[42] = obj5;
myList['foo'] = 'bar';
```

Javascript's arrays can thus be used as maps. You can "clear" an entry by setting it to `undefined`.

Comment: whoooooaaaa there. Just use `myList.push(obj)`. Don't manually index!

Comment: Actually this is all terrible advice. -1